# Can help make array with only odd numbers from array in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need help. I trying make array only with odd numbers but I don't want use arraylist because I only want array.

Input array like this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

I am trying to get odd only array like : [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

```
val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
val arraylist = arrayListOf<Int>() 
for(i in 0..array.size - 1) {
    if(array[i] % 2 != 0) 
        arraylist.add(array[i])
}
val oddarray = arraylist.toArray()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use **[filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html)**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val numbersArray = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    val oddArray = numbersArray.filter{ it % 2 != 0 }.toTypedArray()
    print(Arrays.toString(oddArray)) // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
}
```

Comment: How would it be if i wanted to do it with 1..1000000? and do it with for(I in 1..1000000) and print only the odd numbers.